# wrong number of arguments (0 for 4) where have I gone wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to list a table with filtered parameters from database to the table. I assign default parameters to them, but I get error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 4)

In my model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

scope :filtered, lambda {|count_min, count_max, city, company_status| where(:company_status => company_status, :ap_veh_count => count_min..count_max, :office_adress_city => city, )}
```

In controller:

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :confirm_logged_in

def list
        params[:sort] ||= "name"
        params[:direction] ||= "asc"
        params[:company_status] ||= "3" 
        params[:count_min] ||= "8"
        params[:count_max] ||= "20"
        params[:city] ||= "Rīga"
        @companies = Company.filtered.order(params[:sort] + " " + params[:direction])
end
```

In view:

```
<% @companies.each_with_index do |company, i| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
    <td><%= company.ap_veh_count  %></td>
    <td><%= link_to company.name, {:action => 'view', :id => company.id} %></td>
    <td><%= company.office_adress_city %></td>
    <td><%= company.phone %></td>
    <td><%= company.company_field %></td>
    <td><%= company.email %></td>
    <td><%= 'taisīt' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Atlasīt", {}, :class => 'btn btn-success btn-mini' %></td>

</tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to pass the params to your filter method at

```
@companies = Company.filtered(params[:count_min], params[:count_max], etc.).order...
```

You may want to define your scope as:

```
scope :filtered, lambda { |*args|
  count_min = args.shift || 8
  count_max = args.shift || 20
  city = args.shift || "Rīga"
  company_status = args.shift || 3

  where(
    :count_min = count_min,
    :count_max = count_max,
    :city = city,
    :company_status => company_status
  )
}
```

In order to have defaults for your values. But you still have to pass the params (even if they return nil) so that in case they a set, they would override the defaults.

Comment: Maybe you can help me also to define by default to have all values ? :)

Comment: OK, but I still have to put in some default values. I want it to filter all possible values from that column of DB

Comment: And maybe you can explain what did you do there. I am a RoR beginner :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@companies = Company.filtered( !!! )
```

you should pass there `count_min, count_max, city, company_status`